# I built/was building/in/for

Tags: past-tense

Do you agree?

> I built this house for 5 years. - wrong
>
> I built this house in 5 years. - correct
>
> I was building this house for five years. - correct

In what contexts could "I was building this house for five years" be used?

Comment: If you built the house yourself and took five years to do it!

Comment: Thank you Kate. As usual, I am interested in the version which I divulge. I know that it can be rephrased but I am not interested in it. So, I'd like to know your reaction to the original versions ONLY.

Comment: You asked in what context you would use that sentence! The continuous tense emphasises that it was an ongoing process that took a long time; probably the builder was an amateur doing it in their spare time.

Comment: OK. I thought you would also confirm whether my CORRECT/WRONG estimations were correct. As for the context. I thought there should be something else, like "I was building a house for 5 years and then I quite" in other words. Does the continuous form imply that it wasn't finished. Or it can imply?

Comment: Do you mean 'and then I **quit**? No, it doesn't necessarily imply that the house was left unfinished. Yes, your other estimations are correct.